# Quick way to filter elements out of an array that are x numbers apart

Tags: php, arrays

How to quickly remove elements in an array that are < 5 apart from each other quickly.

example:

```
array(1, 3, 5, 8, 11, 15);
```

needs to return the following cause they are more than 5 if you calculate the difference:

```
array(1, 8, 15);
```

This seems like it should be a built-in function in php for this.  But I'm baffled.

Comment: I am a bit confused.. you want to keep number >= 5 or exactly what ?

Comment: Keep numbers that are 5 or more apart from each other.

Comment: A simple for loop would do it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in for this, but it's a pretty easy thing to accomplish.

First, sort your array, unless it's already sorted.

```
sort($your_array);
```

Initialize your result array with the first element, and then iterate the array. Each time you get to a value at least 5 greater than the previous value, add it to the result and reset the previous value to that value.

```
$result[] = $previous = reset($your_array);
foreach ($your_array as $value) {
    if ($value - $previous >= 5) {
        $result[] = $previous = $value;
    }
}
```